# Printing JSON encoded data from PHP file into a 2 column table

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

Below are the results from PHP JSON encoded file.

```
[{"type":"pie","name":"Class","data":[["Nari",70],["Giri",45],["Balu",25],["Babu",82]]}]
```

I want to print data values into two column table.

```
| nari | 70 |  
| giri | 45 |   
| balu | 25 |  
| babu | 82 |
```

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: This problem is a really easy one, so please incluse what you already tried like @Uchiha asked. This problem has been solved and been documented before, it just takes a quick search for you to solve it on your own, if you still fail after attempting what you found, you can come here and ask about a specific problem in your code rather than asking the community to solve your problem without trying yourself.

Comment: Use json decode u will get an array with associative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pitty that you don't show you attempts so far. On the other hand it's shortly before christmas so...

```
$json = '[{"type":"pie","name":"Class","data":[["Nari",70],["Giri",45],["Balu",25],["Babu",82]]}]';
$object = json_decode($json);
foreach($object[0]->data as $row) {
  echo "|".strtolower($row[0])."|".strtolower($row[1])."|<br>";
}
```

Comment: Either OP added the jquery tag falsely or he gets his JSON from his PHP service and wants to decode and add it to his HTML with jQuery rather than load the complete HTML in his PHP service.